# how to change relativelayout to linearlayout in android studio

Tags: android

[image]

In Eclipse there is an option for changing the layout, but in Android Studio there is no such option.

Comment: If you edit the XML, simply replace the tags

Comment: i know that but it's not work properly when changing relative to linear layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply change the main layout to linear layout to make it linear layout

Answer (score 0):

Move to text from design then make change, Relative layout to Linear layout.
This may change the design of your Activity. you need to make some changes in it as per your requirements.

Comment: This looks like an answer to me.